# Subtracting two cells based on values in another cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate the duration of presence of animals that are photographed by an motion-sensitive camera every few seconds as long as there is activity in front of the camera.  We make the assumption that if the animals are not present for 6 minutes, we consider it a new occurrence of animals and new data point.

I'm trying to create a macro that will calculate the duration of time in which animals are present in front of the camera. Here is an example, where I want to subtract the value in with ** two stars ** from the value several records higher with * one star *. I put #hash-marks# around the Difference of Time values that are greater than 6 minutes for ease of reading.

```
 Photo # Date       Time        Difference of time     Duration of visit
    1   2/9/2012   *8:01:30 PM*      NA                      0:08:48                    
    2   2/9/2012    8:01:31 PM      0:00:01         
    3   2/9/2012    8:01:36 PM      0:00:05         
    4   2/9/2012    8:01:54 PM      0:00:18         
    5   2/9/2012    8:02:36 PM      0:00:42         
    6   2/9/2012    8:02:48 PM      0:00:12         
    7   2/9/2012    8:03:07 PM      0:00:19         
    8   2/9/2012    8:03:23 PM      0:00:16         
    9   2/9/2012    8:04:18 PM      0:00:55         
    10  2/9/2012    8:04:42 PM      0:00:24         
    11  2/9/2012    8:05:02 PM      0:00:20         
    12  2/9/2012    8:05:52 PM      0:00:50         
    13  2/9/2012    8:07:08 PM      0:01:16         
    14  2/9/2012    8:08:59 PM      0:01:51         
    15  2/9/2012    8:10:09 PM      0:01:10         
    16  2/9/2012  **8:10:18 PM**    0:00:09         
    17  2/9/2012   *8:18:08 PM*    #0:07:50#                0:01:22     
    18  2/9/2012    8:18:11 PM      0:00:03         
    19  2/9/2012    8:18:23 PM      0:00:12         
    20  2/9/2012    8:18:34 PM      0:00:11         
    21  2/9/2012  **8:19:30 PM**    0:00:56         
    22  2/10/2012  *8:36:51 AM*   #12:17:21#                0:01:44     
    23  2/10/2012   8:38:00 AM      0:01:09         
    24  2/10/2012   8:38:06 AM      0:00:06         
    25  2/10/2012   8:38:08 AM      0:00:02         
    26  2/10/2012   8:38:17 AM      0:00:09         
    27  2/10/2012   8:38:33 AM      0:00:16         
    28  2/10/2012 **8:38:35 AM**    0:00:02         
    29  2/12/2012   9:15:00 AM     #0:36:25#                     X
```

I've worked from several examples including [this one on copying based on other cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866683/copying-cells-in-excel-based-on-values-in-other-cells), [this one that sums certain rows if conditions are met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19693001/vba-loop-through-rows-sum-up-certain-rows-if-condition-is-met), and possibly the closest, [this one that adds and subtracts values based on values in other cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476979/excel-vba-adding-and-subtracting-values-in-different-cells).  I developed the following draft macro, but I'm new to VBA and can't get the pieces to fit together.

```
Sub CalculateDuration()

Dim duration As Date

'I basically want this to mean search down row D (Difference of time column) for values that are greater than 6 minutes

duration = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range("D:D")
        If cell.Value >= Range("G2").Value Then

'Cell G2 has the 6 minute value in it (i did it this way since it's set as a time value) although I could also add a 00:06:00 if that would work.

              ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = X - ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

              'I need to point the value of X to be the next value in column C that is just one row higher than the next value in Column D that's >= 0:06:00 minutes. I'm not sure the best way to go about that... perhaps a nested if/then?

'I also think I may need something to make this write or end properly...

              End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Just for clarification, you want the macro to calc the 'Dur of visit' column?  Does the real data have the `*`s and `#`s to be stripped out first or those are purely for illustration in your example?

Comment: So you're starting with a clean three column or four column dataset?

Comment: @DeanMacGrego, Yes, I need to calculate Duration of Visit column. The real data does not have *s or #'s.  they're just for illustration of the cells i need calculating.

Comment: @Ken, the original dataset has 30 columns, but I've stripped these out for convenience of illustration.  I think I can work from something that works on this.

Comment: I'm curious about the -1 on my question. I tried to follow the posting instructions carefully. I realize my attempt at the VBA code is pretty sad, is that why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not using VBA, but the formulas could be adopted and inserted into VBA code.

This is my result:
[image]

Columns A, B, C are the data.

Cell D2:

```
=B2+C2
```

Cell E2:

```
=IF(ROW(D2)=2,0,D2-D1)
```

Cell F2:

```
=IF(ROW(A2)=2,1,IF(E2<6/60/24,F1,F1+1))
```

Cell G2:

```
=IF(F2=F1,"",INDEX($D$2:$D$30,MATCH(F2+1,$F$2:$F$30,0)-1)-INDEX($D$2:$D$30,MATCH(F2,$F$2:$F$30,0)))
```

Comment: +1: I vastly favor this approach, much cleaner and extensible.